# will intercession be allowed or not?

Tags: prophets, day-of-judgement, shafaah

so, i've come across this point and i wanted to ask more about it, because im not seeing much about it

so there are a few verses that say:

> "O children of Israel! call to mind My favor which I bestowed on you
> and that I made you excel the nations. And be on your guard against a
> day when ONE SOUL shall not avail ANOTHER in the least, neither shall
> intercession on its behalf be accepted, nor shall any compensation be
> taken from it, nor shall they be helped". S. 2:47-48
>
> "Not your desires, nor those of the people of the Book (can prevail):
> Whosoever works evil, will be requited accordingly. Nor will he find,
> besides God, any protector or helper. If any do deeds of
> righteousness, - Be they male or female - and have faith, they will
> enter Heaven, and not the least injustice will be done to them" S.
> 4:123-124
>
> "And warn with it those who fear that they shall be gathered to their
> Lord - there is no guardian for them, nor any intercessor besides Him
> that they may guard (against evil)". S. 6:51
>
> "Again, what will explain to thee what the Day of Judgment is? (It
> will be) the Day when no soul shall have power (to do) aught for
> another: For the command, that Day, will be (wholly) with Allah". S.
> 82:18-19

do these verses speak against the idea of intercession by the prophets on the day of judgement?